# Magento 2: Is it possible to add search column in ui component?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, magento2.3.1, customer-grid, ui-grid

How can I add filter row in customer grid just like fixed PHP grid using UI component? I don't want to change any other things of UI component grid.

[image]

Comment: I think this functionality can be added in block grids, not UI component grid because the ui component has its own filters outside the grid under the filter option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible to add a filter like a block grid in the UI grid. Ui Component has its own filters. You can enable that by adding `<filters name="listing_filters"/>` in the `<listingToolbar>` Ui grid.

> ```
> <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
>          ....
>       <filters name="listing_filters"/>
>          ------
> </listingToolbar>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> You can try below code, it's not tested though

```
<filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridFilters</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">filters</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.listing_top.bookmarks:current.columns.${ $.index }.visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <filterRange name="id">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                        <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <filterInput name="from">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">from</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">from</item>
                            <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">From</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </filterInput>
                <filterInput name="to">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">to</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">to</item>
                            <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">To</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </filterInput>
            </filterRange>
            <filterInput name="title">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">title</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterInput>
            <filterRange name="created_at"  class="Magento\Ui\Component\Filters\Type\DateRange">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">created_at</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
                        <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_lists_listing.test_lists_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <filterDate name="from">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">from</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">From</item>
                            <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">From</item>
                            <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string" translate="true">MM/dd/YYYY</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </filterDate>
                <filterDate name="to">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">to</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">To</item>
                            <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">To</item>
                            <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string" translate="true">MM/dd/YYYY</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </filterDate>
            </filterRange>  

            <filterSelect name="status">
                <argument name="optionsProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
                    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Sugarcode\Test\Model\Status</argument>
                </argument>
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                        <item name="caption" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select...</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterSelect>

        </filters>
```

**Hope it helps.**

Comment: We have tried this way but It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in view/adminhtml/ui_component/yourxmlfile

Add this code below closing of `</datasource>`

Then run cache flush, and upgrade commands

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <exportButton name="export_button"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters" />
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>            
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
```